# How is the path expression built when calling the search API for Form Builder?

Tags: orbeon

When accessing the Form Builder summary, which lists the forms I currently have access to, I see the search API is called with

```
<query name="application-name" 
       path="xh:head[1]/xf:model[@id = 'fr-form-model'][1]/xf:instance[@id = 'fr-form-metadata']/*[1]/application-name[1]" 
       inline-label="" type="xs:string" control="output" 
       search-field="true" summary-field="true" match="substring" />
```

How/where is the `path` expression built?

Answer (score 0):

1. It is built by the Form Runner summary page, the same way for Form Builder as for other forms, [looking for elements with the `fr-summary` class](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/4.1-ce/src/resources/apps/fr/summary/view.xhtml#L256).
2. So the summary page can find those element, Form Builder has [hidden outputs with that class](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/4.1-ce/src/resources/forms/orbeon/builder/form/form.xhtml#L51).
3. Those outputs reference real [binds in Form Builder's model](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/4.1-ce/src/resources/forms/orbeon/builder/form/model.xml#L226).
4. Form Runner's summary page builds the `path` expression by [going through the ancestors of the bind](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/4.1-ce/src/resources/apps/fr/summary/view.xhtml#L293) mentioned in the previous points, and building and building an expression concatenating the `ref` on those binds.